# Encrypt specific row mysql

Tags: mysql, encryption

is there any possible way to encrypt a specific mysql row?

```
| meta_id | post_id |    meta_key   | meta_value |
+---------+---------+---------------+------------+
|   0000  |   0000  |     1234      |    data    |
+---------+---------+---------------+------------+
|   1111  |   1111  |     0000      |    data    |
```

There are already columns in mysql created, but the data is not encrypted.

Is it possible to encrypt a specific row? For example i only need to encrypt the meta_value of the row where meta_key is 1234.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you talking about a one way encryption or something else?

Comment: The row stores a users personal code, i need it to be not clearly visible in the database, but when the code is needed for a specific task, i need it to be the original one

Comment: So probably `AES_DECRYPT()` & `AES_ENCRYPT()` - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
According to your comment you can use functions

```
FROM_BASE64(str)
TO_BASE64(str)
```

Comment: Any suggestions on how to do it every time a new row is inserted? I know it would be better to just edit the php to add an encryption before posting, but i don't have a possibility to do that.

Comment: Just use MD5 function in insert query.

Comment: [Using salted md5 for passwords is a bad idea](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)